# How can I retrieve the next row's value in a set?

Tags: t-sql

I want to iterate on a table and get records from next row ordering by starting date but I want to do this by handling rows id by id for example:

Main Table

```
ID       |         StartingDate            |      PlannedFinishDate  

 1            2017-01-13 17:48:05.150           2017-01-15 12:00:00.00
 1            2017-01-14 14:15:09.000           2017-01-16 12:00:00.00
 1            2017-01-16 09:40:30.000           2017-01-18 12:00:00.00
 2            2017-02-06 12:00:00.000           2017-02-10 12:00:00.00
 2            2017-03-01 13:45:00.000           2017-03-05 12:00:00.00
 3            2017-02-09 11:31:16.830           2017-02-11 12:00:00.00
```

Table after fetching from next row:

```
ID       |         StartingDate            |      PlannedFinishDate  

 1            2017-01-13 17:48:05.150           2017-01-16 12:00:00.00
 1            2017-01-14 14:15:09.000           2017-01-18 12:00:00.00
 1            2017-01-16 09:40:30.000           NULL
 2            2017-02-06 12:00:00.000           2017-03-05 12:00:00.00
 2            2017-03-01 13:45:00.000           NULL
 3            2017-02-09 11:31:16.830           NULL
```

Comment: There is no "next" row in a table. There is *no* order unless you explicitly use the `ORDER BY` clause. You may *accidentally* get rows back in the order they were stored *IF* the databases uses a single core for processing and no operation that may alter the order. If two cores are used, the ordery is arbitrary

Comment: BTW why *iterate*? A table isn't a file. You read the rows you want at once, not line-by-line. Why don you use `ORDER BY ID, StartingDate` and retrieve all the rows you need?

Comment: Of course can be iterated through a table,it is called **Self Join**.I think that my example is explanatory

Comment: No. Cursors iterate. Self joins **join** a table to itslef just like any other without any kind of iteration. The result is still a set. They don't even have a special operator, they are just joins. The example doesn't actually explain anything. In fact, where did those `NULL` entries come from? You said you wanted the rows to come by ID and starting date, not *modify* them

Comment: did you mean something else by *iterate*? That word means retrieving results one by one. Your data though shows a *modification*. For each starting date you seem to be asking for the *next starting date's* finish date

Comment: I thought that it can be solved by join,it means without modifying, Null values come from join because the row, which has maximum starting date when grouped by id, doesn't have any record of plannedFinishDate as it is fetched from next row.

Comment: You asked for the wrong thing thand didn't describe the *actual* question. You want to get the next finish value per ID. That's easy with an analytic function

Comment: Yes, maybe I've used wrong word for that but exactly like you said, I want each starting date to have next starting date's finish date.

Comment: I already posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you don't actually ask about iteration. You seem to want to retrieve the *next* planned finish date for each starting date.

You can do that easily with the [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) function. This function returns the next value in a result set. It requires an `ORDER BY` clause in order to know what the next row is. It also allows you to specify a `PARTITION BY` clause to partition the result set.

Since you want to find the next planned finish date per ID, you need to `PARTITION BY ID` :

```
select 
    ID, 
    StartingDate,
    LEAD(PlannedFinishDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartingDate ASC)
        AS NextFinishDate
FROM SomeTable
```

If there is no next value, NULL is returned.

This snippet

```
declare @table table (ID int, StartingDate datetime, PlannedFinishDate datetime)
insert into @table (ID,StartingDate,PlannedFinishDate)
values
( 1,'2017-01-13 17:48:05.150','2017-01-15 12:00:00.008'),
( 1,'2017-01-14 14:15:09.000','2017-01-16 12:00:00.008'),
( 1,'2017-01-16 09:40:30.000','2017-01-18 12:00:00.008'),
( 2,'2017-02-06 12:00:00.000','2017-02-10 12:00:00.008'),
( 2,'2017-03-01 13:45:00.000','2017-03-05 12:00:00.008'),
( 3,'2017-02-09 11:31:16.830','2017-02-11 12:00:00.008')

select 
    ID, 
    StartingDate,
    LEAD(PlannedFinishDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY StartingDate ASC)
        AS NextFinishDate
FROM @table
```

Returns :

```
ID  StartingDate            NextFinishDate
1   2017-01-13 17:48:05.150 2017-01-16 12:00:00.007
1   2017-01-14 14:15:09.000 2017-01-18 12:00:00.007
1   2017-01-16 09:40:30.000 NULL
2   2017-02-06 12:00:00.000 2017-03-05 12:00:00.007
2   2017-03-01 13:45:00.000 NULL
3   2017-02-09 11:31:16.830 NULL
```